# Days Difference

Tags: php, strtotime

How can I make `$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01")` a dynamic? I mean ("2010-01-01") a ("dynamic")?

Here's the code:

```
 $started = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_started', true);
 $now = time(); // or your date as well
 $your_date = strtotime("$started");
 $datediff = $now - $your_date;
 echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: what does 'a ("dynamic")' mean? You haven't really explained what you want to achieve very well.

Comment: remove "" from this: $your_date = strtotime($started);

Comment: it's working now..dynamic means..i can set sa variables on it like the one rahul answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass variable without quote.

```
$your_date = strtotime($started);
```

Even **your code works fine too** but try removing quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$startdate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wtf_started', true))));
$now = new DateTime("now");
$datediff = date_diff($startdate,$now);
echo $datediff->format('%d days');
```

Comment: my code is closed to work..i missed to removed the "" on the $started variable.

Comment: click on the upper arrow mark and right sign on this answer top left side